# %0 doesn't returns current path in batch

Tags: batch-file, self

I have this easy script in hello.cmd

```
for %%a in (*.*) do if not "%%a"=="%0" del %%a
```

I tried running it but it seems that the current script hello.cmd gets deleted, as i know `%0` should return the path to the current file but it don't.

---

I also tried running in another script just `echo %0`
and i get returned `%0` instead of the path.

So i was wondering why it doesnt return `c:\path\to\file\hello.cmd`? Is there another way to get the current path?

Comment: How about changing `"%0"` to `"%~nx0"`?, and whilst you're at it, `del %%a`, to `del "%%a"`, or even `del /a /f "%%a" >nul`?

Comment: @Compo semms i forgot to add setlocal in  my script but thanks anyways!

Comment: That's still irrespective of my advice AnonHexo. The main points I was making was that `%%a` could contain spaces or poison characters, _(hence the necessary doublequotes)_, and more importantly, `*.*` will only expand to a basename plus extension, so will unlikely match `c:\path\to\file\hello.cmd`, which includes the drive and path, _(hence the `%~nx` expansion modifier)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO %%0=%0
ECHO %%~f0=%~f0
ECHO %%~dpnx0=%~dpnx0
ECHO %%~nx0=%~nx0
ECHO %%~p0=%~p0
```

Perhaps this might help. Notice what happens when you use simply `hello` instead of `hello.cmd`

Comment: i tried running tour code and it works fine, thanks